# How to insert multiple rows with timestamp using pg-format?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

so I have table `employees` with columns arrange like so

| id | name | department | position | country | jobdesc | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

with `pg` in node I would like to add data into multiple rows at once, the data kind of like this

```
[
    ["vini", "tech", "staff", "ID", "software engineer"],
    ["vidi", "tech", "CTO", "IN", "software engineer"],
    ["vici", "HR", "staff", "ID", "people"]
]
```

In `pg` node I could just make them as a variable and assign to the query with template literals, but I discovered that by using `pg-format` you can make it much better.

But the problem is, if I want to insert those data with timestamp I couldn't do it because if nested array datas I should either use `%s` or `$L` when formatting the query like this :

```
const pgformat = require('pg-format');

const insertQuery = pgformat("INSERT INTO employees (name, department, position, country, jobdesc, created_at) VALUES %L", nested_array_data_above);
```

By doing so the format of the `insertQuery` would be like this :

```
INSERT INTO employees (name, department, position, country, jobdesc, created_at) VALUES ('vini', 'tech', 'staff', 'ID', 'software engineer', 'current_timestamp::timestamp(0)'), ('vidi', 'tech', 'CTO', 'IN', 'software engineer', 'current_timestamp::timestamp(0)'), ('vici', 'HR', 'staff', 'ID', 'people ', 'current_timestamp::timestamp(0)') RETURNING *
```

The format that I need supposed to be like this :

```
INSERT INTO employees (name, department, position, country, jobdesc, created_at) VALUES    ('vini', 'tech', 'staff', 'ID', 'software engineer', current_timestamp::timestamp(0)), ('vidi', 'tech', 'CTO', 'IN', 'software engineer', current_timestamp::timestamp(0)), ('vici', 'HR', 'staff', 'ID', 'people ', current_timestamp::timestamp(0)) RETURNING *
```

am I still going to need `pg-format` with this type of case?